# getElementsByTagName recursively on a page with iFrames

Tags: javascript, iframe

Trying to use helpful code provided at [using document.getElementsByTagName on a page with iFrames - elements inside the iframe are not being picked up](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11144479/using-document-getelementsbytagname-on-a-page-with-iframes-elements-inside-the) but both samples seem to look into first "level" of iframes and not inside of iframes inside other iframes.

Tried:

```
const subtreeSet = (root, theset) => {
    if (!theset) theset=new Set();
    if (!root || theset.has(root)) return theset;
    theset.add(root);
    if (root.shadowRoot) {
        Array.from(root.shadowRoot.children).forEach(child => subtreeSet(child, theset));
    } else {
        if (root.tagName === 'IFRAME') { try { root=root.contentDocument.body; theset.add(root); } catch (err) { root=null; /* CORS */ } }
        if (root && root.getElementsByTagName) for (const child of root.getElementsByTagName('a')) subtreeSet(child, theset);
    }
    return theset;
}

console.log(subtreeSet(document));
```

expected to see all links, but saw only ones not inside nested iframes.

Comment: Are the iframes on your origin?

Comment: Yes, same origin

Answer (score 0):

the iframe in HTML is a little bit special tag. To you access to this tag you have 2 options `contentWindow` or `contentDocument`. You have the information in this link [Stack OverFlow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17197084/difference-between-contentdocument-and-contentwindow-javascript-iframe-frame-acc).

After, you can check this [other link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1088544/get-element-from-within-an-iframe) to know how to combine these 2 properties. The code should be something like this:

```
var iframe = document.getElementById('iframeId');
var innerDoc = iframe.contentDocument || iframe.contentWindow.document;
var innerTag = innerDoc.getElementsByTagName('a');
```

Remember that in your code you are doing `root.contentDocument.body`, this `.body` is not correct.